# how to Stay signed in 2 weeks when some user login using django 

Tags: python, django, authentication

i want to make user dont need to login my site every day  .

so what can i do  using django ., does set cookies or other things ?

thanks

Answer (score 3):

The [Django session documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/) is fairly easy reading.

The defaults should already allow users to be signed in for two weeks - in fact, the default value is exactly two weeks.

Take a look at your settings for:

- SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE - should be False
- SESSION_COOKIE_AGE - defaults to 1209600 (2 weeks, in seconds)

Have you made sure you have all the necessary middleware installed.

Which session backend are you using?

If you're using the file backend in /tmp, you may have a process cleaning up old files in /tmp in the background.

If you're using the database backend, try load up a few objects in "python manage.py shell".  Something like:

```
>>> from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session
>>> s = Session.objects.all()[0]
>>> s.expire_date
datetime.datetime(2005, 8, 20, 13, 35, 12)
```

Good luck!